# Display list inline inside absolute container

Tags: html, css

I have tried many ways to display the sub-list inline position which is held by absolute container without success. I have also tried to substitute the sub-list by using div but also doesnot work. The only thing works is using table, but I don't really like using table. Any suggestion please?

```css
ul.main > li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 background: red;
}

.sub{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 background: green;
}
ul..sub li {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li>
    1

    <ul class="sub">
      <li>1.1.</li>
      <li>1.1.</li>
      <li>1.1.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul.main > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.sub{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: green;
 white-space:nowrap;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none
}
ul.sub li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
 <li>
   <span> 1</span>
     <ul class="sub">
       <li>1.1.</li>
       <li>1.1.</li>
       <li>1.1.</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works great. So the magic line to fix it is white-space:nowrap?

Comment: ooh, haha... I couldn't tell what you wanted the result to look like.

Comment: and make it normal on ul.sub li{white-space:normal;} for not causing problems after

Answer (score 0):

almost there:

```css
ul.main > li {
    float: left;
 //display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 background: red;
}

ul.main > li > span{
    float:left;
    //display: inline-block;
}

.sub{
 
 background: green;
}
ul..sub li {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li>
    <span>1</span>

    <span><ul class="sub">
      <li>1.1.</li>
      <li>1.1.</li>
      <li>1.1.</li>
    </ul></span>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

you can try `float:left` or display: `inline-block` method